# TypeError: Cannot read property equipmentImage of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

Okay so I am trying to post an equipment image from postman as a form data but I am getting this weird error i.e. Type Error; Cannot read property equipmentImage. I am using `express-fileupload` to upload the image. Can anyone help me, Its been 2 days. I cannot figure it out.

```
app.post('/equipmentsAPI/addEquipments', (req, res) => {
   // console.log(req.files.equipmentImage);

        const file = req.files.equipmentImage;  ------*This line*
        const fileName = file.name;

        file.mv("./equipments/" + fileName);

        if (!(req.body.equipmentName)) {
            res.send({ 'message': 'One of the field is missing or misspelled some field.' });
        } else {

            const newEquipment = new equipments({
                equipmentName: req.body.eq,
                equipmentImage: fileName
            });
            newEquipment.save((err) => {
                if (!err) {
                    res.send({ 'message': 'Succesfully added new equipment' });
                } else {
                    res.send({ 'message': err });
                }
            });
        }

});
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `files` is null, that would be a good place to start. Are you sure your request is being sent correctly?

Comment: ^ that. when you console.dir(req) right above the const file declaration - what do you get? do you get files?

Comment: @altruios In postman -- form data -> [ equipmentImage [file] ] [actual image file].

Comment: when you console.dir(res) that's the 'response' object right? req is the formData being sent? or is that backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys, I just solved the problem. The problem is that for each js file I was creating a new middleware
ex:

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload());
```

Once I removed all middlewares and made the common middleware for all the files, it started working.

Comment: That means your issue was never related to the question. But the two answers addressed the question.

Answer (score 1):

so if req is FormData - which can be accessed by index or by methods (see:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) ... it does not seem to have an object attached named files. try req[0] and req[1] to access the equimentImage and image file respectively.

Comment: req[0]? you do know that req is the request object right?

Comment: I am working under the impression that it is FormData.
your reply to my question indicates that that req is in fact FormData
"@altruios In postman -- form data -> [ equipmentImage [file] ] [actual image file]"

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that you need an `equipmentImage` column in postman with a data type of file as well as setting the body type to `form-data`

[image]

Comment: Yaa. that what I am sending from postman. Well thanks anyways.